# set tf_remap private parameters from console

Tags: ros, remap, namespace, parameter, tf-conversions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!! I'm trying to use the tf_remap node without making a launch file. The problem is that the mapping should be specified in the ~mappings parameter of the tf_remap node.
I tried this but it does not work:

```
$ rosparam set /tf_remap/~mappings "[{/neck_2: /neck_1}, {/left_shoulder_2: /left_shoulder_1}, {/left_elbow_2: /left_elbow_1}]"
$ rosparam get /tf_remap/~mappings
- {/neck_2: /neck_1}
- {/left_shoulder_2: /left_shoulder_1}
- {/left_elbow_2: /left_elbow_1}
$ rosrun tf tf_remap __name:=tf_remap
Applying the following mappings to incoming tf frame ids {}
```

I've studied the ros name convention and everything seems fine from my point of view.
Any Idea?

---

EDITED after the bhaskara suggestion:

I also tested the below example and it does not work:

```
$ rosparam get /tf_remap/mappings
- {/neck_2: /neck_1}
- {/left_shoulder_2: /left_shoulder_1}
- {/left_elbow_2: /left_elbow_1}

$ rosrun tf tf_remap __name:=tf_remap
Applying the following mappings to incoming tf frame ids {}
```

---

EDITED: Third attempt:

```
$ rosbag play gesture_recording.bag tf:=tf_old &

#brute force:
$ rosparam set mappings "[{old: /neck_2,new: /neck_1}]"
$ rosparam set /mappings "[{old: /neck_2,new: /neck_1}]"
$ rosparam set tf_remap/mappings "[{old: /neck_2,new: /neck_1}]"
$ rosparam set /tf_remap/mappings "[{old: /neck_2,new: /neck_1}]"

$ rosrun tf tf_remap &
Applying the following mappings to incoming tf frame ids {}
$ rostopic echo /tf

> [...]
> -- transforms: 
>   - 
>     header: 
>       seq: 0
>       stamp: 
>         secs: 1320600273
>         nsecs: 859003197
>       frame_id: /openni_depth_frame
>     child_frame_id: /neck_2
>     transform: 
>       translation: 
>         x: 1.68099461393
>         y: -0.25899046843
>         z: 0.235416310719
>       rotation: 
>         x: 0.279471530986
>         y: 0.53708064566
>         z: 0.633364982269
>         w: 0.481963528351
> --- transforms:  
> [...]
```

Also tested with the same results:

```
rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='{old: /neck_2, new: /neck_1}'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11875/set-tf_remap-private-parameters-from-console/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently come across the same problem. I continued your brute-force and found a working command:

```
rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /neck_2, new: /neck_1}]' 
Applying the following mappings to incoming tf frame ids {'/neck_2': '/neck_1'}
```

---

Originally posted by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) with karma: 260 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-12-04**:
It worked :-)

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-03-04**:
Remember to play the bag with rosbag play x.bag /tf:=/tf_old (Thanks to @Ben_S)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need the ~: just do 'rosparam set /tf_echo/mappings'.  '~' is not used when the name is already fully qualified (starts with '/').

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-11-14**:
Each of those is subtly wrong in a different way :)  the first one needs to set the node name as you were doing earlier with  '__name:=tf_remap'.  The second one needs to enclose the map in a vector, i.e. [{old: /neck_2, ...}] (note the square brackets).

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-11-14**:
certainly bhaskara. I also tried your suggestion in a third attempt (edited post) with the same results. It is strange, your suggestion seems to be absolutely coherent with the remap documentation: ~mappings ([ {str: str} ], default: [])
'each dictionary in the list must have an "old" and "new" key'

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-11-10**:
Your edited comment doesn't match what I typed.  Look carefully :)

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-11-10**:
which parameter is also incorrect? I tried what you say (see edited comment) :-) I don't understand what do you mean. thanks for the interest :-)

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-11-10**:
The parameter value is also incorrect.  Try something like 'rosparam set /tf_remap/mappings "[{old: /neck_2, new: /neck_1}]"'.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-11-09**:
I tried also that and does not work: